# copy zip file(having sub folder and empty folders) from local computer to ftp folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, ftp

i have a zip file which contains sub directories with empty and non empty folders, i just try to copy the file to ftp folder using mput command but only files are copied without sub directories. below is my code, please suggest

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET current=%cd%
PUSHD ..
SET parent=%cd%
POPD
SET P Fold=Enter Folder Name:
echo user FTP123 > ftpcmd.dat
echo RESULTS>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO LCD "%parent%\%Fold%">> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO CD /Releases/Office >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO MKDIR palaccounts >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO CD /Releases/Office/palaccounts/>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO BINARY >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO prompt >> ftpcmd.dat
echo MPUT palaccounts(02.02.2016).zip>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO bye >> ftpcmd.dat
```

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 182.12.125.631

PAUSE

Comment: The `mput` command will upload the zip file, just as any other file. It won't magically extract the zip file when uploaded. But your comment that *"but only files are copied without sub directories"* is confusing. What does it mean? Do you real mean the the files are extracted from the zip file on upload?

Comment: no martin its doesn't extract any file, after copying to ftp folder when open the copied zip file i can able to see only files, there is no any subfolders

Comment: please have a look on this link for directory structure, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ16ss282dLT251X3B5Vko2M1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How do you *"open the copied zip file"* after copying it to ftp folder? Can you share the zip with us? Or any other that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In any case, this probably has nothing to do with FTP. It's must be the zip file itself.

Comment: please visit this link for the zip file , thanks for your comments, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ16ss282dLaVZnYjdBanFvYm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Again, how do you *"open the copied zip file"* after copying it to ftp folder?

Comment: its not possible to open the zip file in ftp so that i just copy the zip file to desktop and open the zip

Comment: So if you open the ZIP file on desktop before upload, you can see the directories. But if you upload it and download back do desktop, the directories are not there?

Comment: Can you share with the both the ZIP file before upload and after upload&download? How do you download it?

Comment: copied the file by right click on the file and download, please have a look on this look for the downloaded file, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ16ss282dLeTJjMXNFLXNfWFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: visit this link for uploaded zip file, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ16ss282dLaVZnYjdBanFvYm8/view

Comment: If you use a GUI FTP client (like [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)), once you upload the file, does it have the same size as the local original?

Comment: Martin i just download the file using mget command from ftp folder, now it seems fine, but while copying the file manualy such behaviour obtained, do you know the reason?

Comment: What does it mean *"copying the file manually"*?

Comment: manually in the sense, right click the uploaded zip file in ftp and select 'copy to folder' option and save on desktop folder.

Comment: You mean in Internet Explorer?

Comment: i mean we can open ftp folder in windows explorer by typing "ftp://123.43.23.81 "in directory bar it will ask for username and password

Comment: I've uploaded your ZIP to FTP, accessed the FTP with Windows Explorer from Windows 10, used *Copy to Folder* function. The downloaded file is identical to the original.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question. As you found yourself, your upload script it not the problem!

Comment: Small addition to your script - Using unquoted %CD% is dangerous! Use either `"%CD%"` or use `.` or `.\ ` instead of just `%CD%`. For reasons read at: [link]https://thesecurityfactory.be/command-injection-windows.html